# Rails - How to ensure two different validations on same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my MyDomain table I would like to ensure the domain name to be present and at the same time wanted to ensure its correctness by validating with some regular expression.

```
class MyDomain < ApplicationRecord
  validates :domain, presence: true
  validate :domain_invalid_value

  def domain_invalid_value
    url_regex = %r{\A[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?\z}ix
    errors.add(:domain, "invalid value") if domain =~ url_regex ? true : false
  end
end
```

But my `domain_invalid_value` doesn't ensure as I include `validates :domain, presence: true`

Both `localhost` and `google.com` are considered as valid domains which shouldn't be the case while creating or updating.

Comment: Why is the attribute called domain if what you validating is a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format` validation in the same line, that is, along with `presence`; for example:

```
class MyDomain < ApplicationRecord
  REGEX = %r{^(http|https):\/\/|[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$}ix

  validates :domain, presence: true, format: { with: REGEX, message: "invalid value" }
end
```

You can refer to the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers) to get a list of all validation helpers available.

Comment: Hey thanks, just found the same in rails documentation:

validates :domain, presence: true, format: {
    with: %r{\A(http|https):\/\/|[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?\z}ix,
    message: "invalid value"
  }